# How do i greet the logged in user with his username fetched from database?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I'm currently developing chatbot using Bot Framework. I want to greet the user with his name. To do this i want to get the currently logged in user's name and use with the bot. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your setup? Which channel are you using, e.g. webchat or Teams. What kind of identity management system is used and how is the user currently logged in.

Comment: As Mick stated, it depends on how you are implementing the bot and the channel and authentication you are using. A good starting point would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp